# How to interpret the $\wedge$ in $\left[(-2 i \pi x)^{k} f(x)\right]^{\wedge}(\xi)$

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, fourier-analysis

I have seen this notation multiple times and I am not aware if the "$^{\wedge}$" is an operation or just a symbol in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That denotes the Fourier transform.

$$\hat{f} (y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-2\pi i xy} f(x) \, dx$$

Comment: So it is equivalent to $\mathcal{F}[(-2i\pi x)^{k}f(x)](\xi)$ right?

Comment: Yep, that too. I prefer the notation you dropped in here since it actually looks like an operator.

Comment: Alright sounds good, thank you :)